# Traverse text nodes with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

```js
var history = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(history)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="tooltip">
  26 Sep, 17:01  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 16:46  <strong>2.15</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 12:32  <strong>2.05</strong> <span class="minus">-0.20</span><br>
  25 Sep, 13:30  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.05</span><br>
  <br>Opening:<br>25 Sep, 02:28  <strong>2.20</strong><br>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to get the information from the span with id `tooltip`, and bring it to some structured javascript object. Unfortunately I can not use jQuery. (it is an injected code with nightmare.js's evaluate).

console returns

```
[object History] {
  back: function back() { [native code] },
  forward: function forward() { [native code] },
  go: function go() { [native code] },
  length: 4,
  pushState: function pushState() { [native code] },
  replaceState: function replaceState() { [native code] },
  scrollRestoration: "auto",
  state: null
}
```

which looks to me like https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp

The function `getElementById` should return an element, so I could traverse its children nodes and collect the data to something like this:

```
[
  {date: '26 Sep, 17:01', value: 2.25, change: 0.10 },
  {date: '26 Sep, 16:46', value: 2.15, change: 0.10 }
  // ...
]
```

Comment: Not certain what question is? Why do you use `history` as an identifier?  `console.log(history)` appears to be referencing `window.history` object. What occurs when you change `var history = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(history)` to `var _history = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(_history)`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the format of `#tooltip`? If so, that would make it a lot easier. And should the "Opening" row be included in the output?

Comment: `window.history` is read-only.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to get the data from the tooltip in the format that you want.

I defined the expression `/([a-zA-Z0-9,: ]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9+\-.]+)/g` that splits each line into 3 different groups.

1. `([a-zA-Z0-9,: ]+)` relates to your date
2. `([0-9.]+)` relates to the value
3. `([0-9+\-.]+)` relates to the change

In the 3rd group, I kept the +/- because I am guessing that you probably want to keep track if the change was positive or negative.  If you don't want you you could change the 3rd group to `[+|-]([0-9.]+)`.

```
const re = RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9,: ]+) ([0-9.]+) ([0-9+\-.]+)/g);

const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

// get the outerText of the tooltip element

const data = [];

while (item = re.exec(tooltip.outerText)) {
  data.push({
    date: item[1],
    value: item[2],
    change: item[3]
  });
}

/** [[object Object] {
  change: "+0.10",
  date: "26 Sep, 17:01",
  value: "2.25"
}, [object Object] {
  change: "+0.10",
  date: "26 Sep, 16:46",
  value: "2.15"
}, [object Object] {
  change: "-0.20",
  date: "26 Sep, 12:32",
  value: "2.05"
}, [object Object] {
  change: "+0.05",
  date: "25 Sep, 13:30",
  value: "2.25"
}] **/

console.log(data);
```

https://jsbin.com/dovahum/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

So this is like the most stupid solution ever but hey... :)
All you need to do is change the variable name!

```js
var myHistory = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(myHistory)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="tooltip">
  26 Sep, 17:01  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 16:46  <strong>2.15</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 12:32  <strong>2.05</strong> <span class="minus">-0.20</span><br>
  25 Sep, 13:30  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.05</span><br>
  <br>Opening:<br>25 Sep, 02:28  <strong>2.20</strong><br>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

`history` is a read-only global object, so your assignment just doesn't do anything. Except for changing the variable name like in the example above, a more structural solution would be to make sure your scripts are running in a local scope and never in the global scope.

One tried-and-tested way to do this is by wrapping your code in an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
(function(){
var history = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(history)
})() // <-- immediately invoke the function here!
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="tooltip">
  26 Sep, 17:01  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 16:46  <strong>2.15</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 12:32  <strong>2.05</strong> <span class="minus">-0.20</span><br>
  25 Sep, 13:30  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.05</span><br>
  <br>Opening:<br>25 Sep, 02:28  <strong>2.20</strong><br>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

You really should make a habit out of using either IIFE's around your code, or some more advanced module system, to make sure your code **never** runs in the global scope. Otherwise each time you assign to a variable in the global scope you are actually adding properties to the window object! It's one of the dark sides of Javascript but alas we have to live with it.

```js
var x = 10
console.info(window.x)
```

To learn more about using anonymous functions for scoping, creating 'private' variables and other more advanced JS topics I recommend reading [this article by Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), or better yet, order his book [Javascript, the good parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). A very good read imho.

*(I'm hoping recommending a book is not against policies. Feel free to edit out if it is.)*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

1. Change the variable name from a possibly reserved word
2. Split on newline
3. Split on space if you need parts

```js
var tt = document.getElementById('tooltip')
 
console.log(tt.innerText.split("\n"))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="tooltip">
  26 Sep, 17:01  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 16:46  <strong>2.15</strong> <span class="plus">+0.10</span><br>
  26 Sep, 12:32  <strong>2.05</strong> <span class="minus">-0.20</span><br>
  25 Sep, 13:30  <strong>2.25</strong> <span class="plus">+0.05</span><br>
  <br>Opening:<br>25 Sep, 02:28  <strong>2.20</strong><br>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```